# Error al instalar C en Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, youtube

Estoy descargando C para eclipse (cygwin) y he hecho todo lo que viene en este video para importar todo lo necesario (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H55fU-63VEI) y al hacer el make, (control + B) me salta este error en consola. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
20:42:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project LenguajeC 
****
make all 
Building target: LenguajeC.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C Linker
gcc  -o "LenguajeC.exe"  ./hola.o ./holamundo.o   
./holamundo.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Fernando/Desktop/LenguajeC/Debug/../holamundo.c:3: multiple 
definition of `main'
./hola.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Fernando/Desktop/LenguajeC/Debug/../hola.c:4: 
first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:31: LenguajeC.exe] Error 1

20:42:54 Build Finished (took 408ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estás intentando hacer **build** o específicamente **link** de dos archivos en los cuales en cada uno hay una definición de `main`. Eclipse está tomando los dos archivos como parte de un mismo proyecto y por lo tanto intentará generar un solo archivo ejecutable. Intenta crear un proyecto para **hola.c** y otro para **holamundo.c**.

Comment: Funciona pero ¿no puedo tener varios programas metidos dentro de una misma carpeta?

Comment: No para leste caso. No conozco algún IDE de lenguaje C que te lo permita